# Rails - missing Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I am sure there's a solution for this but I can't seem to find anything that works. I try creating a rails new and this the error I keep running into.

rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:24:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound) I've tried bundle install and it still the same errors shows when I try to create a rails new Is there something I am not seeing on how to fix this. I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

Comment: Does your `Rails` project have a file named `Gemfile` in it?

Comment: Had a similar issue, try updating brew, deleting rbenv and reinstall it then reinstall rails by running gem install rails and update bundler

Comment: @HarshGupta it does have a Gemfile

Comment: @TaimurKNaziri Thank you that actually worked not sure why but glad it did!

Comment: Okay, glad it did, you were most likely missing dependencies. I'm going to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is because you are missing some dependencies, this usually occurs if you update or use a different version of Rails and Ruby. I had a similar issue not too long ago.

Run `brew update` , 
Delete `rbenv` and reinstall it 
Then reinstall `rails` by running `gem install rails`
Finally update bundler by running `bundle update`

Hope this works for others!!